# How to update a Google Cloud Function's Runtime environment variables without redeploying it?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Looks like I have to redeploy my google function if I want to change the "Runtime environment variables".

Is there a way to update without redeploying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to update the environment variable without redeploying. The principle is to keep a version consistent. Like this, in case of issue in the new version, you can go back to the previous one. It's the principle for a quick rollback.

Sadly, Cloud Functions not yet allow to go back to a previous version (but it should be in the roadmap, I discussed this months ago with a PM). Cloud Run and App Engine allow this rollback, based on this principle, it's a good practice.

At a DevOps perspective, a change in the Env var is a push in your repo, a new CI/CD job and thus a new deployment.

Comment: Let's say I have 100 GCP Cloud Functions and I changed 1 env variable in .env file - how do I know which functions should I redeploy?

Comment: It's your code, you should master the impact of any changes. nothing except you can do that!